# Why SFTP user can view all files using FileZilla?

Tags: ftp, sftp, windows-server

I created FTP site and I set the permissions for each user and user groups (Admins/Users)
using virtual directory.
Each user has its own directory which he can access and Admins can access all folders inside ftproot folder.

Each user permission worked fine when connecting via FileZilla – on the regular FTP.
Then, I tried setting up the SFTP, for that I need OpenSSH SSH Server. I Installed it using Apps > Apps & Features, started it, and  I created a new Firewall rule for port 22.
When a user connects using SFTP, the permissions I defined are no longer valid and the user can access every folder.

Also, when the user logs in, system creates a new folder called by his username (example: user01) in the main ‘Users’ folder inside VM.
I’ve tried changing the sshd_config file located in the main ssh folder (following these steps https://bensmann.no/restrict-sftp-users-to-home-folder/)
When I try to restart the ‘OpenSSH SSH Server ’ I get an error saying that it can’t start the server.

My question is:

What are the proper steps on creating SFTP with user isolation?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Try asking on [sf] instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you, I will try that in 40 minutes, can you help me in some way until then?

Comment: No, because 1) this question does not belong on this site to begin with, and 2) I don't have an answer to offer you anyway.